# Seeding sclorg/mariadb container

Tags: docker, openshift, redhat, openshift-origin, software-collections

I'm using the [SoftwareCollections MariaDB container](https://github.com/sclorg/mariadb-container) and I can't seem to find a way to initialize the database with some users and data.

The [official mariadb container](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/) provides the very handy `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory. The container runs all `.sql` and `.sql.gz` files at database initialization, but this type of functionality seems to be missing from the software collections image.

Why was this functionality not included with software collections? Is it included and I'm just not looking in the right place?

Answer (score 0):

Typically docker containers allows to setup single admin user and password. You can use this later to connect and seed any data you need. 
This can be done on application level by tools like liquibase or just by kubernetes job depending on your use case.

Comment: Very familiar with default docker setup. My question is specific to the software collections container offered by RHEL/Centos.

I've decided to just extend the mysql container.